# Performance implications of "too many" local variables in method?

Tags: java, android, performance, dalvik, local-variables

I was assigned to extend a certain component of a software (written by someone else). It's written for Android, fully in Java (has no native/c++ components I know of).

When getting familiar with the code, I came across a method (a drawing method for a rendering class). The method involves a big loop that updates objects (and then another method will render them later). The creator of the method seemed to cache all/most member variables and arrays and other objects' fields into local variables *before* the loop. The code looked like this:

```
    float[] coordArr = mCoordArr;
    float[] texCoordArr = mTexCoordArr;
    float[] cArray = mColArray;

    // ... there are further locals too, I didn't copy all here

    float[] color = mColor;
    float r = color[0];
    float g = color[1];
    float b = color[2];
    float a = color[3];

    int texw = mTexW;
    int texH = mTexH;
    Font font = mFont;
    float[] ccords = font.ccords;
    float cf = font.cf;
    float cu = font.cu;
    int len = mCurLength;

    // Update the objects
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

        // A quite big loop body

        // ... all locals are accessed from the loop

    }
```

The rendering component is single threaded, with all of its member variables.

I checked it with Java/Dalvik disassembler, and the bytecode comment says the method uses *41* registers. I assume the author cached them to locals to help the JIT and to save some time for field/array accesses, but isn't **this** high number of locals against performance? I heard about "register pressure", for example.

I just don't want to rewrite the code if not necessary (i.e. if the current code is OK), and in order to profile it, I would need to rewrite it (otherwise there is only one version -- the current one, so nothing to compare it with...).

If using "too" many locals is discouraged, then is there some "optimal" maximum that shouldn't be exceeded? (I know that the system's stack size is hard limit, of course.) Because if that's the case, I might need to revise other parts of the software too (if the original author was kind enough to put everything into locals).

Comment: Is it done for pre-post states like in an animation?

Comment: Some notes: http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

Comment: @pst: thanks. I found an interesting part in it (see my comments below Stephen C's answer). I'm not too experienced in Dalvik and VM mechanism, so not sure how to interpret the quoted part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While lots of local variables is likely to result in "register pressure", that simply means that the compiler is likely to do more memory fetches.  However, the alternative is (for example) replace references to `r` with `colour[0]` which in theory involves an index check and an indirect fetch which *may* result in more memory fetches than can be ascribed to register shortage.

In short, there is no simple answer.

So, I'd be inclined to leave the code alone, especially if

- there is evidence that the original / previous author(s) arrived at the current design as a result of profiling, or
- the code already runs *fast enough* ...

Comment: I experience no perf issues on Samsung Galaxy S3, but I'm going to test it on other phones too, on Monday. BTW quoting the Dalvik link I received in a comment: "Because, in practice, it is uncommon for a method to need more than 16 registers, and because needing more than eight registers is reasonably common, many instructions are limited to only addressing the first 16 registers. [..] In cases where an instruction variant isn't available to address a desired register, it is expected that the register contents get moved from the original register to a low register (before the operation) ..."

Comment: "... and/or moved from a low result register to a high register (after the operation)." Can this somehow burden the JIT/performance? On Galaxy S3, the JIT is powerful, but this software must run on some older versions of the platform too (will test on Monday).

Comment: @ThomasCalc - *"Can this somehow burden the JIT/performance?"*.  It *could* do.  But you also need to consider the flipside of getting rid of the caching; see above.  Also bear in mind that differences in hardware and/or the JIT compiler may defeat your attempts at hand optimizing.

Comment: _"will test on Monday"_ I'm curious, what have those tests shown?

Comment: @aeracode - They probably showed that there was no Monday that week :-)